# How can i subtract number from IP address in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a small question here , I have two `Textboxes` in `VB.Net`.

`Textbox1` value will be entered by user. for example `Textbox1` = 10.200.1.1

I want to auto subtract 100 from the 2nd octet and put the value in `Textbox2`

`Textbox2` = 10.100.1.1

Is that doable in `VB.Net`?

Comment: You need to look at the `IPAddress` class. You also need to spend some time in the Help Center to learn what constitutes an acceptable question here.

Comment: "Is it doable" is usually "yes" - perhaps make your next question on SO a bit more specific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`IPAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress) class of .NET to solve this:

```
Dim ip As System.Net.IPAddress = Nothing

'parse the IP address from user input to make sure the input is valid and check for IPv4.
If System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, ip) AndAlso ip.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
    Dim ipBytes() As Byte = ip.GetAddressBytes

    'just subtract 100 on the 2nd octet if higher or equals 100.
    If ipBytes(1) >= 100 Then
        ipBytes(1) = ipBytes(1) - 100
    End If

    'create the new IP address from modified octets.
    ip = New System.Net.IPAddress(ipBytes)
    TextBox2.Text = ip.ToString()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's split on period, then convert the second to integer, and reduce it by 100, convert it back to a string, and recombine the parts into a whole:

```
Dim ip = ip1TextBox.Text;
Dim bits = ip.Split("."c)
Dim octet2 = Convert.ToInt32(bits(1))
octet2 -= 100
bits(1) = octet2.ToString()
Dim newIp = string.Join(".", bits)
```

Comment: Given that the `IPAddress` class exists specifically for handling IP addresses, using it would be a much better choice.

Comment: I'd agree if they they were mutable, but as you can see by Sebastien's answer it doesn't really save much. In some senses I think it may be better for the OP to gain an appreciation for a generic process of "split a delimited string, manipulate an element, recombine". That they're things that look like IP addresses in this case is neither here nor there in the face of a general solution, but a a solution using IPAddress will only really work for IP addresses